# What more do I have to add to this proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove $\forall n \epsilon \Bbb N$, $n+1\geq2$.
My proof is this "Since n is a natural number the lowest number n can be is 1. When this is the case, 1+1=2, which means the conclusion is true. This means $n+2\geq2$ and $n+3\geq2$ is also true. 
Thus, this completes the proof$.

I keep losing marks on assignments because I forget to add something or I have a weird flaw in my proof, is this okay? It seems short so I know I might be forgetting something.

Also, is there some sort of list I should follow when proving statements like this? Like for POMI, there's 1) base case, 2) IH, 3) IC, is there something like that I can follow for general proofs?

Comment: As it stands, this proof is not correct. I don't understand *how* your claimed proof leads to the statement. Why do the statements $n + 2 \ge 2$ and $n + 3 \ge 2$ tell you anything about $n + 1$? Are you using induction (because you haven't stated so)?

Comment: I think the assignment is designed to practice mathematical induction and the axiom system of $\Bbb N$, if there is any. You might need to write the proof in the standard form of induction.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question is designed for the principle of mathematical induction.  So there is the base case where $n=1$ which you have proven to be true.

For the inductions step, prove that if

(1) the hypothesis holds for $n=k\in\mathbb N$, then 
(2) the hypothesis holds for $n=k+1$.  (Here $\mathbb N = \{1,2,\ldots\}$.)

So, you need to prove that if  (1) $k+1\geq 2$, then (2) $(k+1)+1\geq 2$.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is not correct!  You need to prove more generally! Mathematical Induction might help.

Or assume it is false. Then $$(\exists n\in N): n+1<2$$

Form this we get a contradiction!

Comment: Wait so this statement is false?

Comment: The statement $(\forall n \in N): n+1 \geq 2$ is true. What I'm saying is, assume suppose it is false then we get a contradiction.